# Selecting columns based on its element, not its name

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I want to select all the columns that contain `1`.

```
test.dat <- tibble(
  name = c("A","B","C"),
  alert_A = c(1,1,1),
  alert_B = c(1,1,0),
  alert_C = c(1,0,1),
  alert_D = c(1,0,0),
  alert_E = c(0,0,0)
)

> test.dat
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  name  alert_A alert_B alert_C alert_D alert_E
  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A           1       1       1       1       0
2 B           1       1       0       0       0
3 C           1       0       1       0       0
> test.want
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  name  alert_A alert_B alert_C alert_D
  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A           1       1       1       1
2 B           1       1       0       0
3 C           1       0       1       0
```

In tidyselect, `contains()` is matching based on string pattern on the column's *name*.  What I want is to match based on whether a column contains a numeric value.

My guess is to use `is.element` within select, but how can I achieve this?

```
test.answer <- test.dat %>%
  select(name,~is.element(1,.))
#error
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `where` with a check on the type to return character columns (`is.character`) or (`|`) if it is a numeric type (`is.numeric`), then also check if `any` value is 1

```
library(dplyr)
test.dat %>% 
   select(where(~ is.character(.)||(is.numeric(.) && any(. == 1))))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  name  alert_A alert_B alert_C alert_D
#  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 A           1       1       1       1
#2 B           1       1       0       0
#3 C           1       0       1       0
```

Comment: Suppose there are other columns that are `character` and `numeric` and I do not want them included by specifying the columns I want, i.e., `name` and `starts_with(alert)`.   The simple way would be to `select(name,starts_with(alert))` prior to using your answer, but for the sake of learning, would it be possible to specify it within a single line of `where`?   `select(where(~ .=="name"||(starts_with("alert") && any(. == 1))))` doesn't seem to cut it.

Comment: `test.dat %>% 
  select(name,where(~ starts_with("alert") && any(. == 1)))` works, but if I purposely change `starts_with("alert")` to `starts_with("notalert")` it returns error for where() instead of  just returning `name` column.  Any insight to this?

Comment: @aiorr TRy `test.dat %>% select(name, starts_with('alert') & where(~ any(. == 1)))`

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you can use `colSums` assuming you always want to include the first column.

```
test.dat[c(1, which(colSums(test.dat[-1] == 1) > 0) + 1)]

#   name  alert_A alert_B alert_C alert_D
#  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 A           1       1       1       1
#2 B           1       1       0       0
#3 C           1       0       1       0
```

Or with `Filter` :

```
Filter(function(x) is.character(x) || any(x == 1), test.dat)
```